# Generate Monthly based records in a period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

Here is my query to retreive the report for each month to get the paid and unpaid bookings

```
SELECT tbc.tbcId
    ,tbc.tbcName
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(bb.bbId)
        FROM MyBooking bb
        WHERE bb.tbcId = tbc.tbcId
            AND bb.bbIsPayed = 1
            AND Year(bb.bbDate) = '2016' --proc parameter @year
            AND Month(bb.bbDate) = '7' --proc parameter @month
        ) AS PaidCount
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN bb.bbVAT = 1
                        THEN (bb.bbPrice / 100) * 80
                    ELSE bb.bbPrice
                    END)
        FROM MyBooking bb
        WHERE bb.tbcId = tbc.tbcId
            AND bb.bbIsPayed = 1
            AND Year(bb.bbDate) = '2016' --proc parameter @year
            AND Month(bb.bbDate) = '7' --proc parameter @month
        ) AS PaidAmount
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(bb.bbId)
        FROM MyBooking bb
        WHERE bb.tbcId = tbc.tbcId
            AND bb.bbIsPayed <> 1
            AND Year(bb.bbDate) = '2016' --proc parameter @year
            AND Month(bb.bbDate) = '7' --proc parameter @month
        ) AS UnpaidCount
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN bb.bbVAT = 1
                        THEN (bb.bbPrice / 100) * 80
                    ELSE bb.bbPrice
                    END)
        FROM MyBooking bb
        WHERE bb.tbcId = tbc.tbcId
            AND bb.bbIsPayed <> 1
            AND Year(bb.bbDate) = '2016' --proc parameter @year
            AND Month(bb.bbDate) = '7' --proc parameter @month
        ) AS UnPaidAmount
FROM BookingCategories tbc
WHERE tbc.tbcIncludeReport = 1
    AND tbc.tbcId IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT con.tbcId
        FROM CategoryXTags con
        WHERE (
                con.ttId = 26
                OR con.ttId = 23
                OR con.ttId = 24
                )
        )
ORDER BY tbc.tbcName ASC;
```

I have to run this for a given period of time, example Jan 2016 to Aug 2016.

As of now I run this in a loop by passing a @year and @month variable.

Is it possible to just pass @FromDate and @Todate and generate the report for each month in a same query? I couldnt able to think much in SQL to achieve this.

Comment: Check this http://sqlhints.com/tag/monthly-sum-data-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I think will shrink your process down

```
Declare @Date1 Date = '2016-01-01'
Declare @Date2 Date = '2016-08-31'

Select Period       = EOMonth(bb.bbDate)
      ,tbc.tbcId
      ,tbc.tbcName
      ,PaidCount    = sum(case when bb.bbIsPayed=1 then 1 else 0 end)
      ,PaidAmount   = sum(case when bb.bbIsPayed=1 and 1bb.bbVAT = 1 Then (bb.bbPrice / 100) * 80 ELSE bb.bbPrice end)
      ,UnpaidCount  = sum(case when bb.bbIsPayed<>1 then 1 else 0 end)
      ,UnPaidAmount = sum(case when bb.bbIsPayed <> 1 and bb.bbVAT = 1 Then (bb.bbPrice / 100) * 80 ELSE bb.bbPrice end)
 From  BookingCategories tbc
 Join  MyBooking bb on (bb.bbId = tbc.tbcId)
 Where tbc.tbcIncludeReport = 1
   and tbc.tbcId IN (26,26,24)
   and bb.bbDate between @Date1 and @Date2
 Group By 
       EOMonth(bb.bbDate)
      ,tbc.tbcId
      ,tbc.tbcName
 Order By 1,tbc.tbcName ASC
```

Comment: It has some problem with passing the @Date1 & @Date1. If I remove `and bb.bbDate between @Date1 and @Date2` it shows all records. If I add it shows no records

Comment: Is bb.bbDate a date field?

Comment: @Developer is the value you are using for the variable Date1 less than the value for variable Date2? When using between with dates & datetimes the value on the left has to be older than the value on the right of the statement

Comment: Could be a typo but you mentioned "@Date1 & @Date1"